# Query/Endpoint To Show Available Packaging Quantities

Tags: openfda

I'm currently trying to find the appropriate query or dataset to see all the packaging options (specifically quantities) for a particular drug.

Example: Clotrimazole

This drug comes in both creams and solutions. In an ideal world, the endpoint response/dataset would contain information that would allow me to see all packaging options like so

[image] [image]

I have already been able to pull and construct dosage options (such as 1% cream, 1% solution etc) but, like I said, I can't seem to find the total volumes/quantities for their packaging options. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Violet with the openFDA Team. I'm not sure which endpoint you're looking at, but I think you'll find what you're looking for in the Drug/NDC endpoint, which includes detailed packaging information.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=clotrimazole&limit=100

I hope that helps!

Violet

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the best option, and then we can parse out the desired parts of the packaging information, however I have noticed there's not one standard template being implemented, which makes things more challenging than if it were structured like 

`{
          "package_ndc": "0574-0107-77",
          "description": "1/Packet, 70/Box", (or something)
          "marketing_start_date": "200512 01",
          "sample": false
        }`